# Android Sqlite unique id in whole database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am use sqlite database in android, Is there a way to generate a unique ID in the whole database?(unique id in all tables)

Comment: Create the ID yourself, thats the only way (does not really make sense to do that though)

Comment: If i use uuid from java is safe for this goal?